# В JS, выводящий новость в модальном окне, добавить wordpress-функцию "get_the_date"

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Имеем: плагин, отвечающий за вывод новости в модальном окне вместо перехода на страницу новости. В шаблоне вывода анонса новостей я добавил функцию *get_the_date* для вывода даты публикации новости. В анонсе это работает без проблем. Проблема в том, что в модальном окне нужно также вывести этот блок с датой. Отвечает за вывод модального окна JS-файл с таким содержимым:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('.click-modal').click(function(e){ // Что будет происходить по клику по ссылке

            var post_id = $(e.target).parent().attr('id');

            jQuery.ajax({
                url : posttest.ajax_url,
                type : 'post',
                data : {
                    action : 'post_test_it',
                    post_id : post_id
                },
                success : function( response ) {

                    //alert(response)        

                    result_arr = eval( response );
                    $('.modalWindow').html( '<div class="modalWindow_ContentWrapper"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-close"></i><div class="row"><h1>' + result_arr[1] + '</h1></div><div class="row"><p>' + result_arr[2] + '</p></div></div>' ); 

//'class' => 'col-md-12 clean-paddings img-responsive'                  

                    $('.modalWindow img').addClass('col-md-12 clean-paddings img-responsive');
                    $('.modalWindow').fadeIn('fast');
                }
            });




        });
});

jQuery(function($){
        $(document).bind( "mouseup touchend", function (e){ // событие клика по веб-документу
            var div = $(".modalWindow"); // тут указываем класс элемента
                if (!div.is(e.target) && div.has(e.target).length === 0) { // если клик был не по нашему блоку, и не по его дочерним элементам
                    div.fadeOut('slow'); // скрываем его
                    //div.html(''); // очистка
                    }
                else 
                {
                    var div1 = $(".fa-close"); // тут указываем класс элемента
                        if ( div1.is(e.target) ) { div.fadeOut('slow'); } // скрываем его
                }

        });
});
```

То есть, как я понимаю, тут формируется весь шаблон модального окна. Если бы здесь шла ссылка к какому-то стандартному шаблону (типа content.php), я бы смог добавить/изменить функцию в php-файле. Но как быть в этом случае, я не знаю.
Мне нужно либо вставить дату в этот шаблон, либо изменить его так, чтобы он ссылался на контент новости, шаблон которой я мог бы править в другом месте.
Надеюсь, ситуацию донес.

Также, на всякий случай, прикладываю код второго файла плагина:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_test_enqueue_scripts' );
function ajax_test_enqueue_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'test', plugins_url() . '/ajax-text/test.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );

wp_localize_script( 'test', 'posttest', array('ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ));
}


add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_post_test_it', 'post_test_it' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_post_test_it', 'post_test_it' );

function post_test_it() {

$thisID = $_POST['post_id'];

$post_test = get_post( $thisID );

$imageID = get_post_thumbnail_id( $thisID );
$imageHTML = wp_get_attachment_image( $imageID, 'full');

$arr = array( $imageHTML, $post_test->post_title, $post_test->post_content );

if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) {      
    echo json_encode( $arr );
}
die();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `get_the_date()` отрабатывает на стороне **сервера**, но не клиента. В вашем же случае я могу предложить вызывать ее на стороне сервера (там где происходит обработка ajax запроса), и выводить дату в нужном месте **JavaScript'ом**, так же как вы выводите заголовок и описание новости (как я предположил из-за тегов `<H1>` и `<P>`)

**UPD**
Код который необходимо добавить

php:

```
        $post_test = get_post( $thisID );

        $imageID = get_post_thumbnail_id( $thisID );
        $imageHTML = wp_get_attachment_image( $imageID, 'full');
        $date_post = get_the_date( '', $post_test->ID ); // забираем дату создания поста

        $arr = array( $imageHTML, $post_test->post_title, $post_test->post_content, $date_post ); // добавил в возвращаемые данные дату поста $date_post
```

JS:

```
    $('.modalWindow').html( '<div class="modalWindow_ContentWrapper"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-close"></i><div class="row"><h1>' + result_arr[1] + '</h1></div><div class="row"><p>' + result_arr[2] + '</p></div></div><div class="row"><p>' + result_arr[3] + '</p></div></div>' ); // добавил вывод даты
```

Дата поста будет находиться здесь: `result_arr[3]`

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, я даже не подумал о том, что пытался вставить серверную функцию в клиентскую часть.
К сожалению, я не знаю, как сделать то, о чем вы говорите. Не хватает знаний.

Comment: Покажите код который обрабатывает ajax запрос action : 'post_test_it'

Comment: Боюсь, что я не знаю, где это посмотреть, кроме как в приведенных выше файлах. Поиск по содержимому файлов не дал результатов в других местах.

Comment: Обновил ответ, там есть код который необходимо добавить.

Comment: Спасибо! Это то, что было нужно, проблема решена.